# Connection reset by peer - incoming HTTP to apex REST service

Tags: apexrest

In our PROD and QA environments, we have services running in AWS. These make Apex REST callouts to our SFDC org.

Episodically, some days not at all, some days several times a day, we get this error:

```
https://xxxx.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v10/Foo: 
read tcp yyy.17.0.2:36250->136.146.210.112:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

or (separate/distinct Apex REST class):

```
https://csXX.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Bar: 
read tcp yyy.17.0.2:54910->136.147.40.252:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

We've logged a case with SFDC twice and both times, SFDC has asserted they can't find any issue for the timestamps we provide and instead, blaming our network (which is like blaming Amazon Web Services). Our DevOps staff pushes back and says it is Salesforce. Impasse.

Since `connection reset by peer` [has been characterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean) as the peer slamming down the phone, it would seem that the problem should be at the SFDC end.

As best as we can tell, the Apex class is never invoked as we don't see entries in the debug log for the times in question (and because of aperiodicity of the error, we can't keep debug logs active). Furthermore, even if the Apex class failed, it is at the application layer, not the network layer and one would expect normal HTTP response codes, even if the apex class failed with a gack.

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. Have others seen and resolved this `connection reset by peer`?

*Meanwhile, we've implemented retry logic on the AWS client side.  But these network errors get auto logged into our DevOps monitoring system, firing PagerDuty => miffed AWS-stack engineers*

Comment: Did you manage to get beyond Tier 1 Support?

Comment: Nope.  They looked in logs, found nothing and read from the playbook.